# PHP cURL - How to tell if I'm successfully logged in?

Tags: php, ajax, post, curl

I am trying to find out if my login is successful. 
So I login with my credentials and hit submit
When I hit submit, all it does is include the other site below the post fields
Here is a screenshot before I hit submit:
http://gyazo.com/cecea7aff4947b953ce093f4328722b4
Here is a partial screenshot after I hit submit:
http://gyazo.com/8a03440584c0f9385cb1faef05e11993
I tried entering the correct and incorrect credentials and the same thing is happening.
I am not sure whether or not my login is successful or not. After I login I am planning to post in a members area.

Note: the message post field is not being used right now I will use that for something else, but here is my code:

```
<html>
<div>
        <form method="POST">
            Message: <input name="message" type="text" size="25" /></br>

            Username:<input name="username" type="text" size="25" /></br>

            password:<input name="password" type="password" size="25" /></br>

            <input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />

        </form>
    </div>
    </html>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['message'])){$message= $_POST['message'];}

if(isset($_POST['username'])){$username = $_POST['username'];}
if(isset($_POST['password'])){$password = $_POST['password'];}
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$link = "http://site.com/index.php?section=login;
$datatopost = array (
"auth_key" => "880ea6a14ea49e853634fbdc5015a024",
"referer" => "http://google.com",
"ips_username" => $_POST['username'],
"ips_password" => $_POST['password'],
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $datatopost);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$returndata = curl_exec($ch);
echo $returndata;
curl_close($ch);
};



?>
```

Answer (score 0):

the login is at server side i suppose. you should return something from the file you post to, success or fail.

Do you echo something back after login?

Comment: First you manualy login to that site and find some logo id or heading what ever of the page where you redirect after login. then echo this id or heading

Comment: Can you explain a little more? I think I have an idea of what you're trying to say, but not too sure. The logo is always there, logged in or not.

Comment: what i normally do.

`if($returndata["success"] == 1){
   ## do something, redirect or something
}else{
   ## login fail
}`